# Dynamic s:View title

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

This seems like it should be super easy, but I can't figure it out.  How do you dynamically change the title of a page based on some variable?

By title, I mean the title of my view like this:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="DynamicTitle" creationComplete="init(event)">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is flex data binding.

In order to bind to a variable in MXML, try the following syntax.

```
<s:View ... title="{stringVar}" ... >

[Bindable] //metadata tag makes the variable bindable
public var stringVar:String = "StartingTitle";
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, stringVar has to be declared with the Bindable tag for this to reflect changes on the View. Like so : [Bindable] public var stringVar:String = "someString";

Comment: @BarisUsakli Good catch, I added that in.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in ActionScript do this:

```
this.title = 'New Value'
```

So, let's say you had a TextInput, named myTitleText, like this:

There is an event handler for whenever the title changes.  In the event handler, change the text:

```
protected function onChange():void{
 this.title = myTitleText.text;
}
```